# model_count error in ZINB r pscl analysis

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I am modeling a mediated zero-inflated negative binomial (ZINB) model. I am following the steps of [O'Rourke & Vazquez (2019)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0306460319301078)

A few days ago I was running a different ZINB model which ran perfectly fine. However, today I wrote a different model, same variables, but somehow it doesn't run anymore and gives a strange error. When I try my previous model I suddenly get the same error, namely:

```
Error in zeroinfl(Y1 ~ X1 + M1 | X1 +  : object 'model_count' not found
```

The rest of my code:

```
#loading required packages
library(psych)
library(foreign)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(pscl)
library(nonnest2)
library(lmtest)
library(boot)

#Import data
mydata

#Fit a ZINB model
ex1zinb <- zeroinfl(X1 ~ Y1 + M1 | Y1 + M1, data = mydata, dist="negbin", EM= TRUE)
```

I already checked the assumption for the statistical analyses etc., and it is especially strange that a similar model did run a few days ago and not anymore.I am running R 4, and pscl 1.5.6. It runs more or less with pscl 1.5.2, however it does not converge, not even a simple X1 ~ Y1 zeroinfl. I let it run for over 6 hours and gave no output, while initially it provided the output quite rapidly.

If i look at the zeroinfl() code from pscl there is a model_count object, but it somehow doesn't connect with it. If i run my code without the EM=TRUE i get an error concerning 'system is computationally singular'

Does anyone has some suggestions?

EDIT: I tried the same model using the glmmTMB package which did run normally. Would the issue than be the package?

Comment: do you have a link to the data.. you get the error because the model doesn't fit at some point, hence you don't get the object. I am on pscl_1.5.5 unfortunately

Comment: Sorry if i don't understand you correctly, but isn't the data linked to the model using the data=mydata part? It's just odd since i didn't change anything in the code itself nor the data when i ran this earlier and did converge before getting this error. if i run a simple glm.nb it does run smoothly..

Comment: what i mean is can you share the data somehow? I can only tell where in the code it is giving you the problem. My reasoning is this, if you it on a glm.nb and it's ok, means that when you try to fit a more complex model, it crashes

Comment: one thing you can try is to fit zeroinfl(formula = X1 ~ Y1 + M1 | 1..), if this does crash then it means there is some issue with estimating the zero inflation part

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With trying the Y1 ~X1 | 1 suggestion i get the same error. From an earlier run of the same model zeroinfl(Y1 ~ X1 + M1 | X1 + M1, .. ) i got both significant outcomes in the count and zeroes model. Also, the zeroinfl had a significantly better fit than the glm.nb model. That is what strikes me most. It was running fine, and then i did some updates on R since i couldnt install some packages properly (non-zero errors), and now it doesnt run anymore. Very strange